# Why check if cls is the class in __subclasshook__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class

In the [Python standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__), the example implementation of `__subclasshook__` is:

```
class MyIterable(metaclass=ABCMeta):

[...]

@classmethod
def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
    if cls is MyIterable:
        if any("__iter__" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__):
            return True
    return NotImplemented
```

CPython's implementation of `collections.abc` indeed follows this format for most of the `__subclasshook__` member functions it defines.
What is the purpose of explicitly checking the `cls` argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__subclasshook__` is inherited. The `cls is MyIterable` check ensures that concrete subclasses of `MyIterable` use the regular `issubclass` logic instead of checking for an `__iter__` method. Otherwise, for a class `MyConcreteIterable(MyIterable)`, you would have `issubclass(list, MyConcreteIterable)` returning `True`.

Comment: Just to make sure, is this paraphrasing correct? The most likely case where `cls` is not the class is for a class deriving from the ABC which already cannot create instances of itself without providing implementations of the abstract methods, so in that case there's no reason for `__subclasshook__` to check for the methods.

Comment: @Praxeolitic: No. If you had a class `MyConcreteIterable` subclassing `MyIterable`, and that `cls is MyIterable` check wasn't there, then `issubclass(list, MyConcreteIterable)` would return `True`.