# Why loop through __mro__ and check __dict__ in __subclasshook__?

Tags: python

Here's the example of how to use `__subclasshook__` from the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__):

```
@classmethod
def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
    if cls is MyIterable:
        if any("__iter__" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__):
            return True
    return NotImplemented
```

Someone already asked [why the "if cls" check is necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858285/why-check-if-cls-is-the-class-in-subclasshook), but there is one other thing I don't understand. Why go and look at each `__dict__` in the `__mro__` explicitly? Couldn't one say `if hasattr(C, '__iter__')`? I tried the latter with a toy example and it worked as I expected, but I wonder if there is some subtle difference, or if the style in the docs is that way for "historical reasons".

Comment: `C.__iter__` could be the metaclass's `__iter__`.

Comment: @user2357112 that is a valid answer, you could post it as one.

Comment: I think when magic methods are looked up internally they don't use possibly overriden `__getattribute__` methods, either way I'd expect that if it is in the docs like that it is probably very close to how it is done internally (docs are written by the same people who implement python) which is helpful for people who would need to implement it themselves.